# SQL query to group based on sum

Tags: sql

I have a simple table with values that I want to chunk/partition into distinct groups based on the sum of those values (up to a certain limit group sum total).

e.g.,. imagine a table like the following:

```
Key   Value
-----------
A         1
B         4
C         2
D         2
E         5
F         1
```

And I would like to group into sets such that no one grouping's sum will exceed some given value (say, 5).

The result would be something like:

```
Group  Key    Value
-------------------
1      A          1     
       B          4
           --------  
           Total: 5     

2      C          2
       D          2
           --------
           Total: 4

3      E          5
           --------
           Total: 5

4      F          1
           --------
           Total: 1
```

Is such a query possible?

Comment: @user545242 - This is a problem that should be solved by a reporting engine or outputtted to Excel and enable Excel's subtotal features. It is not the type of problem that you should try to solve in the database.

Comment: @Thomas - I don't agree: non-familiar problem (or problem set) do not mean that sql engine shouldn't do it. It's quite possible that there is a solution given that some constraints are allowed, etc.

Comment: @topchef - We agree to disagree. This question is entirely about presentation. The SQL language is geared towards retrieval of sets. We can use a query to get the set of totals. We can use a query to get the set of the individual amounts. Trying to get the subtotals displayed nicely as in the OP is all about reporting. Even if you could produce a query that would return those results, the data tier code would choke on it. The right answer is to pull the raw data and use a reporting tool.

Comment: I think I will have to play around with the raw data in a scripting/reporting tool, however the requirement isn't about presentation (notwithstanding my silly formatting above).  I just need to group these values sequentially - it's about capacity. I have a pipeline of jobs with a given cost (the value) and a series of engines/buckets with limited capacity and need to spread the jobs out as above.  Thanks for all comments thusfar.

Comment: @user545242 - Is it just that you want the subtotal in the output but not formatted as shown? If that is the case, then that *may* be possible.

Comment: @user545242 - As curiosity, why isn't the second group C,D and F for a total 5? I.e., is the goal to create distinct clumps that are as close to some arbitrary total (e.g. 5) as possible without going over?

Comment: It's more about grouping than formatting yes.  Good question about clumps - in my application order matters so regrettably I can't mix-n-match to optimize.

Comment: @Thomas - let's agree to agree then :-)

Answer (score 2):

While I am inclined to agree with the comments that this is best done outside of SQL, here is some SQL which would seem to do roughly what you're asking:

```
with mytable AS (
    select 'A' AS [Key], 1 AS [Value] UNION ALL
    select 'B', 4 UNION ALL
    select 'C', 2 UNION ALL
    select 'D', 2 UNION ALL
    select 'E', 5 UNION ALL
    select 'F', 1
)
, Sums AS (
    select T1.[Key] AS T1K
        , T2.[Key] AS T2K
        , (SELECT SUM([Value])
           FROM mytable T3
           WHERE T3.[Key] <= T2.[Key]
           AND T3.[Key] >= T1.[Key]) AS TheSum
    from mytable T1
    inner join mytable T2
        on T2.[Key] >= T1.[Key]
)
select S1.T1K AS StartKey
    , S1.T2K AS EndKey
    , S1.TheSum
from Sums S1
left join Sums S2
    on (S1.T1K >= S2.T1K and S1.T2K <= S2.T2K)
    and S2.TheSum > S1.TheSum
    and S2.TheSum <= 5
where S1.TheSum <= 5
AND S2.T1K IS NULL
```

When I ran this code on SQL Server 2008 I got the following results:

```
StartKey    EndKey    Sum
A           B         5
C           D         4
E           E         5
F           F         1
```

It should be straightforward to construct the required groups from these results.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try it out.  If I want to display the full set of keys within a group (assuming I had a group that had more than two) I suppose I could try some BETWEEn magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only two members or less in each set, you can use the following query:

```
Select
  A.[Key] as K1 ,
  B.[Key] as K2 ,
  isnull(A.value,0) as V1 ,
  isnull(B.value,0) as V2 ,
  (A.value+B.value)as Total
from Table_1 as A left join Table_1 as B
on A.value+B.value<=5 and  A.[Key]<>B.[Key]
```

For finding sets having more members, you can continue to use joins.